# How to print text on android bluetooth printer?

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth printer, need help to print text in this printer, is there any way to do this?

the printer has a SDK, `BixolonPrinter.jar`, with Java2op I extracted this to pascal:

[Androidapi.JNI.Interfaces.pas](http://pastebin.com/raw/HnXBpey4)

but when I try to install I get the following error:

> Unable to create process: Unable to install .....\Project2.apk
>   Failure
>   [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

Answer (score 1):

on Samsung Mobile > go to <kbd>settings</kbd>><kbd>Security</kbd>><kbd>Unknown sources</kbd> and click on <kbd>i</kbd>.